# Call a javascript function from popup page - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Google chrome extension that according to parameters given in a form - on the popup page, manipulate the URL.

What is the way to call a javascript function and pass it paramaters.
This is my pop up.html:

```
<button onclick="callIt()">Try it</button>
```

This is my js:

```
function callIt(){
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
 var theurl = tab.url;
var newUrl=theurl+'?asd=yes'
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newUrl});
});

}
```

On the debugger I get:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

So how should I implement it?

Comment: You can't have any inline code, that includes inline `onclick` handlers. Move all of it to an external file.

Answer (score 0):

## Docs From Google

### Content Security Policy

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

### Changes between version 1 and 2

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#manifest-v1-changes

> A content security policy is set to `script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:; object-src 'self' by default. This has a variety of impacts on developers, described at length in the content_security_policy documentation.